# WordPress Rest API: How do we validate with our custom API key?

Tags: rest-api, json, authentication, wp-api

How we can verify "Cancel the header auth" the "endpoint" functions of WordPress with an API key that we produce. (Note: not a different endpoint, original endpoints)

I have my own "Crypto" class/function. In the request, I need to send an encrypted key, "decrypt" the "encrypted key" from "wp-function" and so on, and allow the request.

I need to be able to do all of this on wordpress own endpoint libraries.

**A simple example of my query structure:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/workspace/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?request=<?php echo $encrypted; ?>",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php echo $encrypted; ?>
<?php // "z0/8Q6cuMWBlZGzfTwOVi9HwCpKThN9Ju/o/MywK74vimB467vjGfKqoDVQdyKIdmXCxxE=" ?>
```

**functions.php or e.g. php page: After Decrypt**

```
<?php echo $decrypted; ?>
<?php // "Secret Password" ?>
<?php // I will verify my key, and to let
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function checkApiAuth( $result ){

    $yourEncryptAPIKey = $_GET['request'];

    if( yourDecryptFn( $yourEncryptAPIKey ) === $realKey ):
        $result = true;

    else:
        $result = false;

    endif;

    return $result;           
}
add_filter('rest_authentication_errors', 'checkApiAuth');
```

Comment: Thankyou well done

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use the [`rest_authentication_errors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_authentication_errors/) filter:

> This is used to pass a [`WP_Error`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/) from an authentication method back to
>   the API.
>
> [...] If the authentication method hooked in is not actually being
>   attempted, `null` should be returned [...]. Similarly, callbacks
>   should ensure the value is `null` before checking for errors.
>
> A [`WP_Error`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/) instance can be returned if an error occurs [...]. A
>   callback can return `true` to indicate that the authentication method
>   was used, and it succeeded.

For a code example, you can look how WP implemented their custom check for the `X-WP-Nonce` header in [*wp-includes/rest-api.php* starting at line 807](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L807).

(The function `rest_cookie_check_errors` is [added to the `rest_authentication_errors` filter with priority 100](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L278).)